# Best Practice: transform model to json viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I'm using ASP WebAPI and knockoutJS for a singe page application.

Right now, I have the webfrontend and the knockoutJS viewmodel. Additionally, I have a SQL database (model).

Now I want to get the model data into the frontend. I don't know what is the best way to do this.
Of course, I can serialize the model to JSON. I know the ko.mapping-plugin and also the Razor serialization mechanism.

My problem is: My model is totally different to the viewmodel. I need a transformation mechanism or something.

example model:

1. Table: Country / Cols: ID, Name
2. Table: CitiesInCountry / Cols: ID, Name, CountryID

example viewmodel:

{name: 'Germany', cities: ['Berlin', 'Nuremberg', 'Cologne']}

So the model saves all the available countries + cities and the frontend is just displaying one country with it's cities.

I'm *not* looking for a algorithm. I'm looking for the "best way to do this". Is the transformation part of the controller? Do i need a c# class for the viewmodel (and then serialize it)?

Can somebody point me to a good design pattern / tutorial / sample project ?

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the transformation part of the controller? Do i need a c# class
>   for the viewmodel (and then serialize it)?

YES, you need to create ViewModel in this way -

```
public class CountryViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

Then you are going to use this class to formulate the implementation. Then finally send it using Json Serialization.

```
  [HttpGet]
  public JsonResult GetDate()
  {
      var model = new CountryViewModel();
      // Get data from Database and Initialize/map it to model here or create list<CountryViewModel>
      return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

At the Client side use this kind of code -

```
 // Get data from server
 var getFilteredData = function () {
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "/URL/GetData",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function (data) {                            
                  self.KOObservableVariable(data);
         },
         failure: function (errMsg) {
                  alert(errMsg);
         }
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do all transforamtions on server side, leave for front-end just rendering and UI events. 
You can create some busines logic layer where do all your convertations and in web-api controller just return complete result.

On client side it just recieves result and do as minimum actions as possible.

Example:

```
public class DBTable
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Param1 {get; set;}
    // and others
}

public class ViewModelClass
{
    public string CustomParam1 {get; set;}
    // and so on
}

//in web-api controller 
public ViewModelClass GetData()
{
    return new BLL.Data().GetData();
}

// in BLL namespace Data class
public class Data()
{
    //DAL - data access layer - implement it as you would like. 
    var ViewModelClass result = new DAL.DataDAO().GetData()
        .ConvertAll(x=> new ViewModelClass() { 
            // do all your transformation here
            CustomParam1 = x.Param1,
            // and other
        });    
}
```

Comment: concrete, this means i need a poco-representation of my json-viewmodel? So i implement a c#-viewmodel -> fill it with data from the model (incl. transformation) -> serialize it -> send it to the frontend?

Comment: @user3796786 added some example

Comment: thx, both answers are correct. Both helped me a lot! Personally i like the other answer more, so i choose this as the correct one.